# I want to prevent a navigation controller segue from happening when a row is tapped, but do want to segue when the accessory button is tapped

Tags: swift, tableview, segue

I'm getting an unwanted segue when I tap a tableview cell.  I only want to do the segue when the accessory button is tapped. The current code works when I tap the accessory button on a cell.  But if I tap the content view, a segue happens and my `prepare(for:sender:)` fails because sender isn't an IndexPath, it's an TableViewCell.  BTW, the view containing the TableView is on a navigation controller stack.

I tried deselecting User Interaction Enabled setting for the content view of the table view cell, but that seems to inhibit the accessory button also.

This works as expected

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowDetails", sender: indexPath)
    }
```

When the cell is tapped, this is getting called before the prepare(for:sender:) is called.

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        log.debug("didHightlightRowAt")/
    }
```

I don't know how to prevent the segue when the cell is tapped.  When the cell calls the `prepare(for:sender:)`, I get this error:
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x11edbdaa0) to 'NSIndexPath' (0x10e209cf8).
2019-06-06 12:10:24.086845-0500 Earthquakers[1668:53901] Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x11edbdaa0) to 'NSIndexPath' (0x10e209cf8).

when this code executes:

```swift
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.destination is DetailViewController {
            let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
```

(because sender is a tableviewcell)

Comment: this is too complicated. Are you passing any object to `DetailViewController`? And  how does your `dataSource` looks like?

Comment: @klaudas, yes.  After the "let indexPath..." line in the code above, I get a pointer to the DetailViewController and stuff values into it's local variables.  Complicated?   I guess I didn't describe it well.  It's simple.  When the accessory button is tapped, I perform a segue, the prepare(for:sender:) gets called and everything's dandy.  What's causing the prepare(for:sender:) to get called when the table view cell "content area" is tapped?  *I* certaining didn't write code to do a segue.

Comment: I understood well what you're trying to achieve. Add custom `UIButton` to your cell instead and send `tap` action back to your controller class in `cellForItem at` delegate method